# Executing a particular function on specified core using openMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, cpu-cores

Is it possible to fix one function to run on a particular core using OpenMP?

For example: I have two functions namely: **Foo1** and **Foo2**

And my computer (Linux OS) has two cores: **core0** and **core1**.

So, How can I run application **Foo1 always on core0** and **Foo2 always on core1 simultaneously**?

I am using C++ for coding.

Comment: Read about the term [process affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Novelocrat and @Joachim for their useful comments:

I did it like this:

```
int main() {

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            foo1();
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            foo2();
        }
    }
}

return 0; }
```

Now foo1() runs always on thread 1 and foo2() runs always on thread 2.

At run time set Environment Variable:GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 1"

which binds thread 1 to core0 and thread 2 to core1.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to

1. set the number of OpenMP threads to 2 (`omp_set_num_threads(2)`), and
2. in a *parallel region*, check the thread ID and call `Foo1` or `Foo2` accordingly.

How to do these things is described in the OpenMP documentation.

An alternative approach would be to create two openMP tasks, each running one of your functions.

Comment: Actually I wanted to bind the Foo1 to core0 and Foo2 to core1.I got some commands for binding it: export OMP_PROC_BIND=true will bind the threads to specific cores i.e there will be no switching or we can set the CPU Affinity using:GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 1" It sets Thread 0 to core0 and Thread 1 to core1.